# Using Entity Framework to search for a single item and return it as Data Transfer Object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using Entity Framework and I'm trying to search the database for a single object based on the primary key.

I have a **Movies** database which also has some relational data in other tables.

This is what I'm using currently:

```
Movie newMovie = MovieRepository.FindSingle(id);
```

But this returns all the relations of this row as well.

I have created a Data Transfer Object called MovieDetails which only contains these fields:

```
public class MovieDetails
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public int? BroughtBy { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried searching the database with this, but without success.

```
public MovieDetails FindSingle(int? id)
{
    MovieDetails newMovieDetails = dbContext.Movies.Select(x => new MovieDetails
    {
        MovieID = (int)id,
        MovieName = x.MovieName,
        BroughtBy = (int)x.BroughtBy,
        Director = x.Director,
        Rating = (int)x.Rating
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I search the database for a single row and convert it to this **MovieDetails** format?

Comment: You try to assign `MovieDetails` to `Movie` object. Unless MovieDetails inherits from Movie this won't work

Comment: So I should search with Movie and then somehow convert it to MovieDetails?

Comment: is `Movie newMovie =  ...` a type or that's what is required ?

Comment: That's a type which Entity Framework uses to search the database for Movies.

Comment: Then Roman's answer is a way to go

Comment: `I've tried searching the database with this, but without success.` What _specifically_ didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Where()` to filter records, then `Select()` and `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
MovieDetails newMovieDetails = dbContext.Movies.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => new MovieDetails
{
    MovieID = x.ID,
    MovieName = x.MovieName,
    BroughtBy = (int)x.BroughtBy,
    Director = x.Director,
    Rating = (int)x.Rating
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

And replace this line:

```
Movie newMovie = MovieRepository.FindSingle(id);
```

by this one:

```
MovieDetails newMovieDto = MovieRepository.FindSingle(id);
```

Comment: I get an error saying " 'Movie' does not contain a definition for 'select'.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this:

```
        using (MovieContext dbContext = new MovieContext())
        {
            var newMovieDetails = dbContext.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MovieID == id);

            var MappedDetails = new MovieDetails
            {
                MovieID = newMovieDetails.MovieID,
                MovieName = newMovieDetails.MovieName
            };
            return MappedDetails;
        }
    }
```